# Constructing a custom problem in Pymoo (Picking a subset of Vehicles from a Bag)

Tags: python, pymoo

I am trying to follow this [method](https://pymoo.org/customization/custom.html) to solve an optimization problem. I have a bag of N=100 vehicles which have certain properties. For example cost, rank, and mpg. I am looking to find k=5 subsets of vehicles that have higher mpg and rank than others. N and k can take any values.

Following the [pymoo](https://pymoo.org/customization/custom.html), the evaluation function looks like this:

```py
    def _evaluate(self, x, out, *args, **kwargs):
        out["F"] = np.array([x["rank"], x["mpg"]], dtype=float)
```

Here, x has as many dimensions as many columns for vehicles. In this case, I am using rank and mpg as I want to maximize these.

The guide says to create methods including:

Sampling
Crossover
Mutation

I want to know how can I formulate the above problem in these functions.

1. Sampling: refer the link above, should I create a method that takes 5 random vehicles from bag and return these?
2. Crossover: I am blind to this. What should I be doing in my case?
3. Mutation: I don't know what to implement here.

If somebody has used pymoo, give me some hints on the above so that I can do my implementation.

Many Thanks

*** Here is the updated code for now. I am getting an error (attached).[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Anq9r.png)

```py
from pymoo.algorithms.soo.nonconvex.ga import GA
from pymoo.optimize import minimize
from pymoo.core.crossover import Crossover
from pymoo.core.mutation import Mutation
from pymoo.core.sampling import Sampling
import numpy as np
from pymoo.core.problem import ElementwiseProblem

class SubsetProblem(ElementwiseProblem):
    def __init__(self,L,n_max):
        super().__init__(n_var=len(L), n_obj=2, n_ieq_constr=0)
        self.L = L
        self.n_max = n_max

    def _evaluate(self, x, out, *args, **kwargs):
        out["F"] = np.array([self.L[x][0], self.L[x][1]], dtype=float)
        #out["G"] = (self.n_max - np.sum(x)) ** 2
        

class MySampling(Sampling):

    def _do(self, problem, n_samples, **kwargs):
        X = np.full((n_samples, problem.n_var), False, dtype=bool)

        for k in range(n_samples):
            I = np.random.permutation(problem.n_var)[:problem.n_max]
            X[k, I] = True

        return X

class BinaryCrossover(Crossover):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(2, 1)

    def _do(self, problem, X, **kwargs):
        n_parents, n_matings, n_var = X.shape

        _X = np.full((self.n_offsprings, n_matings, problem.n_var), False)

        for k in range(n_matings):
            p1, p2 = X[0, k], X[1, k]

            both_are_true = np.logical_and(p1, p2)
            _X[0, k, both_are_true] = True

            n_remaining = problem.n_max - np.sum(both_are_true)

            I = np.where(np.logical_xor(p1, p2))[0]

            S = I[np.random.permutation(len(I))][:n_remaining]
            _X[0, k, S] = True

        return _X


class MyMutation(Mutation):
    def _do(self, problem, X, **kwargs):
        for i in range(X.shape[0]):
            X[i, :] = X[i, :]
            is_false = np.where(np.logical_not(X[i, :]))[0]
            is_true = np.where(X[i, :])[0]
            X[i, np.random.choice(is_false)] = True
            X[i, np.random.choice(is_true)] = False

        return X

# create the actual problem to be solved
np.random.seed(1)
L = np.array([[9,13],[9,14],[7,15],[6,12],[8,16],[8,14],[6,12],[3,18],[4,14],[5,14],[8,11],[8,18]])
n_max = 3
problem = SubsetProblem(L, n_max)


algorithm = GA(
    pop_size=12,
    sampling=MySampling(),
    crossover=BinaryCrossover(),
    mutation=MyMutation(),
    eliminate_duplicates=True)

res = minimize(problem,
               algorithm,
               ('n_gen', 60),
               seed=1,
               verbose=True)

print("Function value: %s" % res.F[0])
print("Subset:", np.where(res.X)[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways you can formulate a subset selection problem. You can find a tutorial in the pymoo documentation as well: https://pymoo.org/case_studies/subset_selection.html

There, the binary variables are used and suitable operators are implemented. I think the example provided there should be directly applicable to your problem.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for quick contact. I am following that example. I want to know if I can use a two dimensional array in place of 'L' there? I also don't get why len(L) stands for n_var in INIT. here, I have two variables in my array.

something like this: L = np.array([[9,13],[9,14],[7,15],[6,12],[8,16],[8,14],[6,12],[3,18],[4,14],[5,14],[8,11],[8,18]])

Comment: You can also define a bi-objective optimization problem. Looks to me like you want to do that. Just set to `out["F"]` a list of size two. You can use `L[x].sum(axis=0)`.